# Android app crashes every time i start the previous activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 activities let's say activity Alpha and activity Beta.

in my `AlphaActivity.class` i have the code below:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    cDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public static final String TAG = "XD";

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String u = snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString(),
                        p = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString(),
                        ad = snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString(),
                        f = snapshot.child("floor").getValue().toString(),
                        ns = snapshot.child("notes").getValue().toString();
                Address a = new Address(u, p, ad, f, ns);
                infoArray.add(a.address);
                nameArray.add(a.name);
                phoneArray.add(a.phone);
                writeListView();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Action canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
...
```

Whenever i run that activity works like a charm. I have a button in this one where i start the Beta activity `onClick` like so:

```
public void betaMethod(View view) {
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BetaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In `BetaActivity.class` i do something and then again i have a button where `onClick` acts like below:

```
public void addToDatabase() {
    ...

    finish();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlphaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When that codes executes, my app crashes and the error i get is on the `AlphaActivity.class` down there where i have `p = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString()`. I bet it has to do with the firebase method `onDataChange` but i can't figure it out. Any suggestion please ?

The error i get is:

```
06-04 16:59:16.885 13978-13978/com.example.johng.assosfood E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.johng.assosfood, PID: 13978
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.johng.assosfood.ProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ProfileActivity.java:48)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where ProfileActivity.java = AlphaActivity.java

Comment: we cant help you without the logs......or maybe we can. why are you calling finish()? no need for that.

Comment: Please include the entire error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any line looking like  `cDatabase = FireabseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

> phone child must contain value in numbers and you're retrieving it as a String

Instead of `p = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString()`.

Always use `p = snapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class);` or

`p = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class));` do this for all snapshots.

Also in `public void betaMethod(View view)` use finish(); after `startActivity()` it's just good practice

Comment: there are some dots in the onCreate method. These dots represent the cDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); and other declerations.

Comment: that was my problem the toString() instead of (String.class). Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

When you starting a new activtiy your code is

```
public void betaMethod(View view) {
    finish(); //here
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BetaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Why you finish your activity when launching `intent` it means when you came back it can not find your last `activity` and in that case it can not load your last activity because it finished before launching `intent`. and if you want to remove `backstack` from activity then use

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

so remove finish from here and check your code works fine.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: whether i have finish before the startActivity or after or not at all i get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing wrong with calling `finish()` ! in fact if you go back and forth too many times without calling `finish()` this can cause an `OOM exception` as the stack fills up with instances of each activity. I think you just need to call the `finish()` method after `startActivity()` not before.

Comment: But the question is app is getting crashed when calling the previous activity. If finish() called anywhere, then the previous activity will not be available in the stack.

Comment: well I tried to reproduce this !! and the app didn't crash ! but putting finish() after startActivity made the transition faster. Anyway his problem is not coming from the finish() method as suggested we should see the logcat report.

Comment: @user3816569 With finish() or without i get the exact same error no matter what!

Comment: @JohnGkouziotis that's why I mentioned that you need to post the error because the problem is not from finish() please update your question with exact error you're getting so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

When you store long numbers in Firebase Database, it probably stores it in Float data type. So maybe to get value of "phone" you should try

```
String.valueOf((Float)snapshot.child("phone").getValue());
```

Comment: all my values stored in database are strings not long or int even the phone numbers.